# Java Html Parser and Closing Tags

Tags: java, html, parsing

How do I handle closing tags (ex: `</h1>`) with the Java HTML Parser Library?

For example, if I have the following:

```
public class MyFilter implements NodeFilter {

 public boolean accept(Node node) {
  if (node instanceof TagNode) {
   TagNode theNode = (TagNode) node;
   if (theNode.getRawTagName().equals("h1")) {
    return true;
   } else {
    return false;
   }
  }
  return false;
 }
}

public class MyParser {
 public final String parseString(String input) {
  Parser parser = new Parser();
  MyFilter theFilter = new MyFilter();
  parser.setInputHTML("<h1>Welcome, User</h1>");
  NodeList theList = parser.parse(theFilter);
  return theList.toHtml();
 }
}
```

When I run my parser, I get the following output back:

```
<h1>Welcome, User</h1>Welcome, User</h1>
```

The NodeList contains a list of size 3 with the following entities:

```
(tagNode) <h1>

(textNode) Welcome, User

(tagNode) </h1>
```

I would like the output to be "`<h1>Welcome, User</h1>`". Does anyone see what is wrong in my sample parser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

I think you must rely on [isEndTag()](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/htmlparser/nodes/TagNode.html#isEndTag()) API in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Your filter is accepting too many nodes.  For your sample input, you want to create a `NodeList` that has only a single node--for the `<h1>` tag.  The other two nodes are children of that first node so should not be added to the `NodeList`.

---

If you add the following code, you may see better what the problem is.

```
for (Node node : theList.toNodeArray())
{
    System.out.println(node.toHtml());
}
```

It should print

```
<h1>Welcome, User</h1>
Welcome, User
</h1>
```